# Relationships between the tutte polynomial?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

What is the relationship between a graph $G_n$ with $2$ vertices joined by $n$ edges and the graph of $C_n$ (complete graphs)?  And what is the relationship between their Tutte polynomials?

Tutte polynomials:
$$T(G_n;x,y)= x+y+y^2+\ldots+y^n-1$$
$$T(C_n;x,y)= y+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n-1 $$

Comment: Well, apparently $T(G_n;x,y)=T(C_n;y,x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $C_n$ denotes the complete graph, your expression for its Tutte polynomial is wrong. It would be more usual to have $C_n$ denote the cycle on $n$ vertices.
And $C_n$ is the planar dual of $G_n$, and therefore we expect to get one polynomial from the other by swapping $x$ and $y$. (Because this relation holds
for the Tutte polynomials of a planar graphs and their duals.)

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to say a complete graph. Cn is the graph on n vertices, in which every pair Vi, Vi+1 is joined by en edge, and the pair Vn and V1 is also joined by an edge.